# How to install Canon LBP 3300 printer in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

Recently I changed to Linux from windows and I have a printer **Canon LBP 3300**. which is working fine in windows but in ubuntu it's not working. I can't print anything also there is no option to print both side in the paper and it seems to missing many options. How can I fix this ? I tried to find canon printer driver but can not find anything for my printer model. please give me a detail solution that I can understand.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Have you added your printer in Settings -> Devices -> Printers? once the printer is added there, be sure to select the correct driver (likely not the default selection) and once the printer is here you can use the Additional Printer Settings or Gear icon to configure.

Answer (score 1):

First, navigate to Settings -> Devices -> Printers and see that your printer is added. If not click the add button and select appropriate driver (select it manually, don't use the default driver).

Once printer is showing up in above dialog, click the printer to select and then click the "Aditional Printer Settings Button".

[image: Printer Settings]

You will be presented with a small dialog box titled "Printers - localhost" you then select your printer and under the "Printer" menu click "Properties". You will get yet another dialog that will give you your configuration options for your printer.

The option to set up double sided is under "Printer Options":

[image: Double Sided Print Options]