# Problem while installing Canon LBP 3300 printer in Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Tags: 18.04, printing, canon

Well, I'm giving step by step photo here.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfHbG.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lxkys.png)

[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dE8GM.png)

[Image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1o0w.png)

[Image 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dvzw7.png)

Maybe my installation process is not right. I think, I should install Canon LBP 3300 printer driver for Linux. I have the file for Linux, but I don't know that how to install it. Please help me!

**Note that:** The printer is fine. It works properly in Windows after installing driver.

Edited post: I can't find the driver for LBP 3300. [Here the photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGCV0.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Canon LBP 3300 printer in Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1078769/how-to-install-canon-lbp-3300-printer-in-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: Yeah, I've seen this. But I can't find my Canon LBP 3300 printer driver in the list.

Comment: what happens when you pick the one which says recommended for the lbp 33xx  ?   often its the same drivers even though they are labelled differently for each permutation of the model names

Comment: Well, after your comment, I've selected LBP 3360 and tried to print a test page. But it is saying, 1 job processing (for 5minutes+). Still now it is saying that.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install the driver from here:

https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/printers/laser/i-sensys_lbp3300.html?type=drivers&language=en&os=linux%20(64-bit)

To Install:

make sure you have the build essentials package installed.

`sudo apt-get install build-essential`

Change to the directory of the downloaded driver:

`tar xvzf PACKAGENAME.tar.gz`

cd to the extracted folder and then :

`make && sudo make install`

Comment: Can you clarify this for me:

"Change to the directory of the downloaded driver:

tar xvzf PACKAGENAME.tar.gz"

Should I cd to the downloaded folder & write this command(I know, I should change PACKAGENAME)?

Comment: yes. In your case it would be something like `tar xvzf linux-capt-drv-v271-uken.tar.gz`

Comment: After extraction, I've write these commands:  "make && sudo make install". But it is saying, "make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop." (I've write these commands in the extracted folder)

Comment: You have some dependencies missing most probably run `./configure` first and then the rest of commands. It will tell you what dependencies are missing.

Comment: "bash: ./configure: No such file or directory"
In linux-capt-drv-v271-uken folder, there are 3 sub folders(32-bit_Driver, 64-bit_Driver, Doc, Src). In the 64-bit_Driver folder, there are more 2 subfolders(Debian, RPM). In the Debian folder, there are 2 files(cndrvcups-common_3.21-1_amd64.deb, cndrvcups-capt_2.71-1_amd64).

Comment: Ok buddy so I downloaded the file and you are in luck. Go to your file explorer: Go to the folder you just extracted and then go to 64 bit > Debian > Double click on the Common deb file and install

Comment: Okey. I've installed the driver correctly. I've also selected the correct driver(Canon LBP 3300 CAPT ver.1.5). After clicking on "test print" it is saying, 1 job processing(still now. maybe it's 2minutes+).